# Como faz para dentro do Modal conforme os dados no Banco de Dados deixar input checkbox macados (checked)?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, modal

Na minha Tabela em **Produtos** no meu **BD** tem o campo **Processos**

e fiz um modal para que a pessoa marque os processos em que a peça possa vir sofrer, cada letra corresponde ao um processo, que correspondente a primeira letra, exemplo **C.** = Corte, **D.** = Dobra, **S.** = Solda, **CA.** = Calandra, **M.** = Montagem, **P.** = Pintura

> Exemplo:

Fiz uma tabela onde lista todos os produtos e com um botão editar para abrir um modal, conforme a imagem abaixo

```
<table id="tabela1" class="table table-bordered table-striped table-hover tabela2">
    <thead class="thead-dark">
        <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Grupos</th>
            <th>Códigos</th>
            <th>Revisão</th>
            <th>Descrição</th>
            <th>Ação</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        @foreach ($produtos as $produto)
        <tr>
            <td>{{ $produto->id }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produto->gruposdescricao}}</td>
            <td>{{ $produto->codigo }}</td>
            <td>{{ $produto->revisao }}</td>
            <td><a href="#" data-target="#viewModal{{ $produto->id }}" data-toggle="modal">{{ $produto->descricao }}</a>
            </td>
            <td>
                <a href="#" class="text-success"><i class="fas fa-eye fa-lg view" id="view"></i></a> &nbsp &nbsp
                <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-edit fa-lg editarProduto" id="editarProduto" data-target="#editModal"
                        data-toggle="modal" data-whatever="{{ $produto->processos }}"></i></a>
            </td>
            @endforeach
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Utilizando como exemplo o item do **ID 1** o processo dele é **C.D.P.M.**

Ao abrir tela modal para editar o processo eu precisaria que aparecesse os itens marcados. Como no exemplo acima, tem que aparecer marcado conforme a imagem abaixo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Eu estou usando o exemplo do bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/#varying-modal-content

no campo `data-whatever="C.D.P.M"` conforme cada item em uma tabela.

```
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
  // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
  // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
  var modal = $(this)

  modal.find('#processos').val(recipient)
})
```

Daqui para frente eu não consegui fazer com que as checkbox correspondentes de cada letra aparece marcadas.

Alguém consegue me ajudar, obrigaodo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Como você não mostrou o código HTML da modal com os checkboxes, considerando que os checkboxes possuem `value` com as letras das palavras (ex, `value="C"` para "Corte"), basta converter o valor do `data-whatever` em array com `.split(".")` e em seguida percorrer a array com `.map()` buscando na modal os checkboxes que possuem os `values` que coincidem com as letras e marcá-los:

```js
$('#exampleModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {
   var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
   var recipient = button.data('whatever') // Extract info from data-* attributes
   // If necessary, you could initiate an AJAX request here (and then do the updating in a callback).
   // Update the modal's content. We'll use jQuery here, but you could use a data binding library or other methods instead.
   var modal = $(this);
   
   recipient.split(".")
   .filter(function(e){ return e }) // remove valores vazios
   .map(function(e){
      modal
      .find(":checkbox[value='"+e+"']")
      .prop("checked", true);
   });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="C.D.P.M.">Abrir modal</button>
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
            <input type="checkbox" value="C"><label>Corte</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="D"><label>Dobrar</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="S"><label>Solda</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="U"><label>Usinagem</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="CA"><label>Calandrar</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="E"><label>Estampar</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="P"><label>Pintura</label>
            <input type="checkbox" value="M"><label>Montagem</label>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Muito obrigado, agradeço muito ajuda